# Laravel 5.1 Fetch Rows between start_time and end_time (two different fields)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've been working on reservation project, I collect request (time_start and time_end) and add 1:30 hour to each so i can prevent user to select conflicts.

I tried using "Between" already but it doesnt seems to work.

```
->whereBetween('reservation_time_start', [$time_from, $time_to])
->whereBetween('reservation_time_end', [$time_from, $time_to])
```

I also tried this,

```
->whereRaw('((reservation_time_end <= ? AND reservation_time_end >= ?) OR (reservation_time_start >= ? AND reservation_time_start <= ?))',[$time_end, $time_start,$time_start, $time_end])
```

It work but in some cases like between some time range, i dont get any results. Like This.

```
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
| id | reservation_time_start | reservation_time_end |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
|  1 | 10:00:00               | 13:00:00             | <- i need to get this
|  2 | 12:00:00               | 14:00:00             |
|  3 | 14:00:00               | 15:00:00             |
+----+------------------------+----------------------+
```

**sample user input's:**

```
$reservation_time_start = 12:00:00 (-1:30 Hour)
$reservation_time_end = 14:00:00 (+ 1:30 hour)
```

and when i execute my code, it returns null. Please help.

Comment: that is conversion, my question is how to fetch data from database base from user input between two time range in two different fields.

Comment: Can you check the datatype of these column in DB it should be time. 

AND
->whereBetween('reservation_time_start', [$time_from, $time_to])
->whereBetween('reservation_time_end', [$time_from, $time_to])
will be interpreted as AND 
what you need is orWhereBetween

Comment: yes, its in 'time' dataType.

Comment: Try this

->where(function($query) use ($data){
                    $query->whereBetween('date',array($data['datefrom'],$data['dateto']))
                    ->orwhereBetween('time',array($data['datefrom'],$data['dateto']));
                })

Comment: i have two different fields in my database @RohitDalal, reservation_start_time and reservation_end_time. so using between in my db will only work in one field.

Comment: ->where(function($query) use ($data){ $query->whereBetween('reservation_start_time',array($data['datefrom'],$data['d‌​ateto'])) ->orwhereBetween('reservation_end_time',array($data['datefrom'],$data['datet‌​o'])); })

Comment: @RohitDalal I tried but no results, here's the code with injected data. >where(function($query) use ($data){ $query->whereBetween('reservation_start_time',array(10:30:00,15:30:00)) ->orwhereBetween('reservation_end_time',array(10:30:00,15:30:00));

Comment: Can you share a pastebin url with your code so that i can check it properly?

Comment: You should use both date and time because you can have problem with todays time and tomorrow time

Comment: @RohitDalal https://pastebin.com/MqBY245J my pastebin. I just copied the single method from my controller.

Comment: Are you always getting null AND can you tell me the datatype of reservation_status_id column in your table?

Comment: Have you added times correctly ?

Comment: @RohitDalal https://pastebin.com/K8HfcCgX, not really. in my previous code (in the second block above my post). There are case that i dont get results, like time range of 10:30:00 to 15:30:00, where in my db theres 12:00:00 to 2:00:00.

Comment: In your DB you have record between 12 pm to 2 am but you want result between 10:30 pm to 3:30pm. As i can understand your query is showing correct result.

Comment: no its 12:00 pm, to 2:00 pm also. yes, but as you can see, 10:00:00 to 13:00:00 row didnt show up when i execute my code.

Comment: @jp.palubs what do you want actually ? all reservation started and completed during the start and end time or all reservations happening during the time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Carbon for your problem,

you have user input times as:

```
$reservation_time_start = 12:00:00;
$reservation_time_end = 14:00:00;
```

I suggest you to use date and time, so your user input should be,

```
$reservation_time_start = 2017-07-18 12:00:00;
$reservation_time_end = 2017-07-18 14:00:00;
```

Now, parse these times with Carbon. After that add and substract 1:30 hour from end time and start time respectively.

```
$start_time = Carbon::parse($reservation_time_start)->subMinutes(90);
$end_time = Carbon::parse($reservation_time_end)->addMinutes(90);
```

After, this you can use simple query like this,

```
DB::table('reservation')->where(function($query)  
     use($start_time,$end_time){      

         $query->where('reservation_time_start','>',$start_time)
               ->where('reservation_time_start','<',$end_time);
     })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use($start_time,$end_time){   

         $query->where('reservation_time_end','>',$start_time)
               ->where('reservation_time_end','<',$end_time);
    })
    ->get();
```

From the above query you will get reservations in the given range of time.

Hope you understand.

**UPDATE**

In your case, You have to consider following cases in reservations.

1. Reservation Starting during given range of time.
2. Reservation Ending during given range of time.
3. Reservation Starting and Ending during given range of time.

Comment: i already have carbon parse in my time range, and also tried your sample code but still get no result of reservation_id = 1 (above table). i selected time from 10:00:00 to 13:00:00.

Comment: @jp.palubs what do you want actually ? all reservation started and completed during the start and end time or all reservations happening during the time ?

Comment: reservations during that time, so the user/client will prevent to click those time.

Comment: Your problem seems quite unclear, You want to prevent user to make reservation for specific duration of time where there are already some reservations Am I right ?

Comment: yes, to make it clear, heres the full detail of my controller. https://pastebin.com/cxdVUMKe

Comment: @jp.palubs  After a view of your link, As I understand you need all active reservations during the given time interval, you can use `orWhere ` with my answer which gives you perfect result.

Comment: @jp.palubs I have updated my answer take a moment to view it.

Comment: i've tried, but it loads all rows, because the query will return true even if reservation_time_start is > reservation_time_end because of OR operator. thanks anyway.

Comment: @jp.palubs As I understand, I've again updated query try the latest one.

Comment: it works now, thanks to you. i just found out that i adding 90 minutes of time in $start_time instead of subracting it.

Comment: @jp.palubs congrats any way and glad it helped you